# Word for "cannot bring oneself to do something."

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a battle scene where one of the characters can't bring himself to attack the enemy. I want to describe the feeling when he lies on the ground, surrounded by the carnage of war, when he knows that he *can* engage in it, but he can't bring himself to do so out of pure human decency. For example:

> John paused as he saw Marcus lying on the ground in the distance. Was he injured? No, ***he can't bring himself to do it***.

I thought of words like "unmotivated", "apathy", etc., but they seem to imply a degree of laziness, which isn't present here.
Are there any words like what I'm looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for ***reluctant***?

Comment: He wasn’t that ***cold-hearted***...

Answer (score 1):

One good example I can think of is "humbled", though you'd probably need a qualifier after it like "humbled by the suffering", or something. "Humbled" means something made someone feel something very strongly in their heart, such as witnessing extreme suffering or a very nice gesture. It doesn't necessarily mean they could not act, but that is implied by the rest of your example (the fact he is on the ground and could be seen as "injured").

Other examples with similar meanings could be "overwhelmed" or "overcome", but, again, these would be helped by a qualifying phrase afterwards. They mean that the nature of a situation was too much for the person to cope with and usually imply an inability to act properly.

In your example, based purely on my own native English thought flow while reading, I would consider "overcome" the most intuitive.

Edit: Just remembered some more examples: "shaken" or "disturbed". They're slightly stronger than "humbled".